# Is there a way to use torch.autograd.gradient in parallel in Pytorch?

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, gradient, derivative

I am trying to train some network where the loss is not only a function of the output but also the derivative of the output w.r.t. the input. The problem is that while computing the batch output can be done in parallel with the modules with Pytorh, I can't find a way to do the derivative in parallel. Here's the best I can do in serial:

```
import torch
x=torch.rand(300,1)
dydx=torch.zeros_like(x)
fc=torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
x.requires_grad=True
for ii in range(x.size(0)):
    xi=x[ii,0:] 
    yi=torch.tanh(fc(xi))    
    dydx[ii]=torch.autograd.grad(yi,xi,create_graph=True)[0]
dydxsum=(dydx**2).sum()
dydxsum.backward()
```

In the code above, x is split to save memory and time. However, when the size of x becomes large, parallelization (in CUDA) is still necessary. If it has to be implemented by tinkering Pytorch, a hint to where to start will be appreciated.